# AngularJS $timeout within a resource factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I currently have an angular application which upon user login calls a service to begin a server call to refresh a count, only allowing for a server side return if the user is authenticated.

```
resource.approvalsCount = 0;
var approvalsCountTimer;
resource.getApprovalsCount = function (username) {
    return resource.query({
        username: username,
        q: 'approvalsCount'
    }).$then(function (response) {
        resource.approvalsCount = response.data.count;
        approvalsCountTimer = $timeout(resource.getApprovalsCount, 3000);
        return resource.approvalsCount;
    });
};
```

When a user logs out I am attempting to cancel that counter otherwise the server will return a 401 unauthorized error by calling a function based on the resource:

```
resource.cancelTimers = function () {
    $timeout.cancel(approvalsCountTimer);
}
```

The issue is that the counter continues to run even after I call the cancel upon the $timeout which returns a 401 from the server.  Console logging out the return the cancel function returns true (cancel has worked).  I have tried several different placements of the begin of the $timeout to no avail, is there a way to ensure that all of the $timeouts are canceled?  I don't understand what I am missing in this configuration.

**EDIT**

```
angular.module('resources.approvals.approvals', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Approvals', ['$timeout', '$resource', function ($timeout, $resource) {
    var resource = $resource('/approvals/:username/:requestID', {}, {
        'update': {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
    resource.approvalsCount = 0;
    var approvalsCountTimer;
    resource.getApprovalsCount = function (username) {
        return resource.query({
            username: username,
            q: 'approvalsCount'
        }).$then(function (response) {
            resource.approvalsCount = response.data.count;
            approvalsCountTimer = $timeout(resource.getApprovalsCount, 3000);
            return resource.approvalsCount;
        });
    };
    resource.cancelTimers = function () {
        $timeout.cancel(approvalsCountTimer);
    };
    return resource;
}]);
```

Comment: How did you call `cancelTimers` in your code?

Comment: I call it within the logout process, so on my main menu controller i have a $scope.logout = function(){ Resource.cancelTimers(); }

Comment: Is approvalsCountTimer defined in the closure of resource object? Can you post the entire resource code?

Comment: Added code changes above.

Comment: you are actually recursively calling getApprovalsCount in the timeout, is that what you really need?

Comment: I think so?  I want the timer to perpetually call itself to refresh from the server on login, and on logout stop the timer.  If there is a better way of doing that I am all for it, I just thought that would work the best.

Comment: It appears that if I cancel after one timer has been created and is in the process of finishing its callback then it is unable to cancel that one and when it returns its value from the server it comes back an unauthenticated.  Not sure how to resolve that but doing a little more logging based on your example below was helpful in that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code looks good. It got to be something else.

I simplified a bit and you can see it on the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qKFEZ/1/). it simulates the http call every half second and the `cancelTimes` will be called in 4 seconds.

```
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('Approvals', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var resource = {};
    resource.approvalsCount = 0;
    var approvalsCountTimer;
    resource.getApprovalsCount = function (username) {
        console.log(approvalsCountTimer);
        approvalsCountTimer = $timeout(resource.getApprovalsCount, 500);
    };
    resource.cancelTimers = function () {
        console.log("stopped");
        $timeout.cancel(approvalsCountTimer);
    };
    return resource;
}]);

function Ctrl($scope, $timeout, Approvals) {
    Approvals.getApprovalsCount();
    $timeout(Approvals.cancelTimers, 4000)
}
```